# sql save row count of query every day

Tags: sql, datetime, save, rowcount

I want to create a view or table that counts eg. total number of students on that day the query is executed and add row results each day. Problem is the date column on table changes everyday to the current date.

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*) AS no_of_Students
     ,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) as DATE
FROM mySchool 
WHERE students=1

No of student  .  Date
-----------------------
8              .  2019.02.06
15             .  2019.02.07
```

(next row should auto update for next day when running the query)

Comment: Create a calendar table (or cte) having all dates of interest. OUTER JOIN that table.

Comment: Will it be able to save the count results of that day and not over write It

Comment: Show the structure of your mySchool table, why you are using Getdate(), don;t you have any date column in your table?

Comment: I do, but the date column changes everyday to the current date. Its a processdate

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `GETDATE()`, You need to pick the date column you have in your mySchool table.

You need to write your query like following.

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as [no_of_Students]
,CAST([DateCoulumn] AS DATE) as [DATE]
FROM [mySchool]
GROUP BY CAST(DateCoulumn AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(DateCoulumn AS DATE)
```

**Note:** You need to replace `DateCoulumn` with the correct column name.

Comment: will the results for tomorrows date be added as a new row, even though the date column would have updated to tomorrows date

Comment: Yes, if the table contains the date, it will appear for sure.